# How do I embed a quicktime movie into an iphone web app using javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, video, quicktime, dashcode

I'm creating an iphone webapp in dashcode for the first time and I can not figure out the code for embedding a video into the webapp.I have an html file and have a few pages it switches between but I need to create a function in javascript so when I click a button that it will pull up a video I in quicktime. Any sample code or thoughts?  If anyone could give me some samplecode I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this (completely untested):

```
function showVideo(vidFile) {
    var vidElem=document.createElement("video");
    vidElem.setAttribute("src", vidFile);
    vidElem.play();
}
```

And then invoke it like this:

```
showVideo("your_movie_file.mov");
```

Comment: Tested it on the desktop Safari and it works. It doesn't seem to work in iPhone Simulator, (and in fact, nothing relating to video did) and I don't have a physical device with me at the moment, so I can't test that currently.

Comment: okay thanks alot for the help do I have to embed a quicktime player for it to work on a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

1. create your .html file
2. embed the following code :

<video src="your_movie_file.mov" controls="controls">
your browser does not support the video tag
<video>

3. upload your file to your webserver.
4. test your files. (make sure your movie file in your webserver too...

Comment: yeah I have an html file and have a few pages it switches between but I need to create a function in javascript so when I click a button that it will pull up a video I have in quicktime. Any sample code or thoughts?